# ¿Cómo crear una función que agregue una propiedad a cada objeto de un arreglo si no la tiene?

Tags: javascript

```javascript
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
 
 // La funcion llamada 'agregaPropiedad' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
  // en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que puede tener como propiedades 'nombre' o 'edad'. También
  
// recibe un string llamado 'propiedad'.
  
// Esta función debe agregar la propiedad 'propiedad' y setearla en null a aquellos objetos dentro de 'amigos' que no tengan esa propiedad
  
// Debe devolver el array 'amigos' modificado.
 
 // Nota: Si el objeto dentro de 'amigos' tiene esa 'propiedad' no modificarla.
 
 // Ej:
  // var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
  // agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad') debe devolver [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: null } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }]
```

Comment: Pásate por la sección [ask] y realiza el [tour]. Tu pregunta tiene una calidad muy baja, no indicas que has intentado ni cual es tu duda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejame saber si te sirve para todos los tests

```js
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
    // Itera por cada objeto y con el operador condicional terenario verifica si ya tiene la propiedad con el operador 'in', si no la tiene le agregas la propiedad = null
    amigos.forEach(obj => !(propiedad in obj) ? obj[propiedad] = null : '')
    return amigos
}
console.log(agregaPropiedad( [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], 'edad'))
```

Comment: Si, ahi me paso," !(propiedad in obj) ? obj[propiedad] = null : '')" Me podes decir que es este codigo, para entender mejor

Comment: Si, es lo mismo que decir : if ((propiedad in obj) == false)  {
                                                 obj[propiedad] = null 
                                            };     lo de (propiedad in ob)j lo que esta haciendo es  checar si esa propiedad existe dentro del objeto, devuelve true si lo encuentra y false si no está, por es solo le agrego la propiedad si es igual a falso. Para entender mejor la forma en la que hice la condicional tienes que investigar sobre el operador condicional ternario.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Gracias en serio

Comment: @J.Villasmil esa explicación que diste en comentarios deberías agregarla a tu respuesta.